# Problem with one step in a proof of fundamental theorem of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $k$, $l$ be smooth functions from an interval $I$ into $\mathbb R$ and $k>0$. 
Let's consider system of differential equations

$$
t'=k n,
$$
$$
n'=-k t-l b,
$$
$$
b'=ln
$$
with unknow functions $t,n,b: I\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$.

How to show that scalar products below are zero:
$$
t\cdot t'=0, 
$$
$$
n\cdot n'=0,
$$
$$
b\cdot b'=0.
$$

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. But from the given context, I am guessing that those conditions are assumed to hold initially, and you wish to show that they continue to hold. Am I right?

Comment: I wish to show that Euclidean norms of functions $t,n,b$ are constant. Then if we assume that for fixed $s_0$ norms of $t(s_0),n(s_0),b(s_0)$ is $1$, we obtain that this norms are equal $1$ at each point.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of counterexample. 
Assume that $k,l$ are constant functions. Then
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
t'' & = & kn'\\
 & = & -k^{2}t-klb,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
differentiating again,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
t''' & = & -k^{2}t'-klb'\\
 & = & -k^{2}t'-kl^{2}n\\
 & = & -k^{2}t'-l^{2}kn\\
 & = & -k^{2}t'-l^{2}t'\\
 & = & -(k^{2}+l^{2})t'.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
This equation can be solved for coordinate functions of $t$. 
Then 
$$
t_j(x)=c_{1,j}+c_{2,j} e^{\sqrt{k^2+l^2}x}+c_{3,j} e^{-\sqrt{k^2+l^2}x}.
$$
If I haven't overlooked something, from these you can constructe an explicit counterexample.